# Decode JWT From AWS Cognito Exposes poolId and Client app secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, jwt

I have created an ASP .Net Core application that authenticates against Cognito.

My Authentication Controller looks like:

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/signin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> SignIn(User user)
        {
            var cognito = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);

            var request = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest
            {
                UserPoolId = "ap-southeast-2_mypoolid",
                ClientId = "myclientid",
                AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
            };
            request.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", user.Username);
            request.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", user.Password);

            var response = await cognito.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(request);

            return Ok(response.AuthenticationResult);

        }
    }
```

Startup.ConfigureServices looks like:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Audience = "client key";
                    options.Authority = "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-poolid";
                });
```

I have included this in case it is something I have done in the above.

My Bearer tokens work fine. I auth against Cognito and get my access/id/refresh tokens.
Being new to Cognito and AWS in general and being curious, I ran my tokens at https://jwt.io/ and found that they contained my poolId and clientId. I was under the impression these are to be hidden away with the utmost security.

Is this normal or is it something I have done. I feel that maybe this shouldn't be exposed so easily?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its normal, Only the secret should not be exposed.

Comment: And how do I achieve that?

Comment: for browser based applications, you should not create an app client with a secret, you should create one without secret

Comment: This is at this stage an API only.

Comment: Apologies - It is NOT an app client secret.. It is my App Client id that is decoded. Under App client secret I have (no secret key).

Comment: it's ok to expose the app client id as well.